# Rails, Devise remove registration of specific model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller, devise, routes

I have two models `Admin` and `Partner`. Both of them are created by devise. Now I want to remove registration from `Admin` so I wrote this in my routes:

```
devise_for :admins, skip: :registrations
```

However when I try to run page where `Admins` login page appears. It throws me error:

```
undefined method `new_admin_registration_path' for #<ActionDispatch::Routing::RoutesProxy:0x0000000d4d9650>
```

I know that before there was **registration link** I removed registration from my path for `Admins`, now it tries to create link with registration path.

There is [this tutorial](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Set-up-devise-as-a-single-user-system) of how to remove registration from forms, But I want to have registration for my `Partners` while `Admins` does not have.

Question is how to remove registration links from `Admins` while keeping it in `Partners`??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could generate Devise views for your Admins:

```
rails generate devise:views admins
```

This will create a set of views in views/admins, including a partial named "_links.erb.html". You can remove any unneeded link from that one, and it should not impact your Partners views.

Comment: Thank you for answer. I have found another way, I needed to remove `:registerable` from my model. But your solution will be useful in future